# extra repetitive records in select statement with join

Tags: sql, join, subquery, distinct

I have 2 tables, "read_barcodetolid" and "serial_barcode". both of them have ordernum field in common. I want to select rows and do not want to have repetitive values, 
at first I used this query:

```
SELECT  distinct(t1.ordernum)
                 , t1.tarikh,
                   t2.city,
                   t2.officeNum,
                   t2.provience
         FROM read_barcodetolid t1
         join serial_barcode t2 on t1.ordernum=t2.ordernum
```

it works fine with just ordernum field. but when I add another field like city,... it makes some repetitve records.

then i wrote this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) ordernum
        FROM read_barcodetolid
        WHERE (ordernum = seri.ordernum)
        ORDER BY ordernum DESC
        ) AS ordernum,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) seri.officeNum
        FROM read_barcodetolid AS read_barcodetolid_2
        WHERE (ordernum = seri.ordernum)
        ORDER BY ordernum DESC
        ) AS officeNum,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) provience
        FROM serial_barcode
        WHERE (ordernum = seri.ordernum)
        ) AS provience,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) city
        FROM serial_barcode AS serial_barcode_1
        WHERE (ordernum = seri.ordernum)
        ) AS city,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) tarikh
        FROM read_barcodetolid AS read_barcodetolid_1
        WHERE (ordernum = seri.ordernum)
        ) AS tarikh
FROM serial_barcode AS seri
WHERE (ordernum IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY tarikh DESC
```

it returns  results but at the end shows some NULL records and when i use "where ordernum IS NOT NULL" it not works

what can i do?
is better solution to get rid of extra repetitive records?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the group by clause

```
SELECT t1.ordernum, MAX(t1.tarikh) tarikh, MAX(t2.city) city, MAX(t2.officeNum) officeNum, MAX(t2.provience) provience
FROM read_barcodetolid t1 join serial_barcode t2 on t1.ordernum=t2.ordernum 
WHERE (ordernum IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY t1.ordernum
ORDER BY MAX(t1.tarikh) DESC
```